# JMS connection from Java SE

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I would like to create a JMS connection from a Java SE application in a ***broker-agnostic*** way.

I'm comparing to JDBC with its URL scheme for database connections. This creates independence from the actual implementation.

For JMS I haven't found something similar. I'm aware that in Java EE the JNDI will fulfill this role, but this is Java SE.

I don't want to tie my code to any particular queue broker as my needs are pretty simple JMS 1.1 send/receive of text messages.

I've looked at Spring Boot too because it is usually good at providing some level of agnosticism. But even with Spring Boot, I do not see such possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNDI *is* the way you write your JMS application to connect in a broker-agnostic way. JNDI client classes are part of Java SE. Both Spring and non-Spring Java SE applications use JNDI for this kind of integration.

Any JMS implementation should also provide a JNDI implementation that can be plugged into your application. Typically this is done by placing a file named `jndi.properties` on your classpath and putting the proper configuration for whatever JNDI implementation you're using into that file. When you create an empty [`InitialContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) the `jndi.properties` file on your classpath is read automatically. The key=value pairs in `jndi.properties` are put into the `InitialContext` so that when you perform a lookup everything works with the implementation you've chosen. You can also configure this programmatically if you like by supplying the implementation specific details to the `InitialContext` via [a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#InitialContext-java.util.Hashtable-).

By using both the JMS and JNDI APIs in your Java SE application and externalizing broker-specific connection details to your `jndi.properties` file you can effectively isolate your applications from broker-specific code so you can deploy your app and work with different brokers with a few simple changes in a properties file.

The JNDI client implementation will come from whoever is providing the JMS implementation. The JNDI client essentially comes in the form of an `javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory` implementation packaged in a jar and there is usually documentation describing the available properties.

Here are a few examples:

- The ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.x broker provides `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` available in their `activemq-client-<version>.jar`. Documentation is available [here](https://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html).
- The ActiveMQ Artemis broker provides `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` available in their `artemis-jms-client-<version>.jar`. Documentation is available [here](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html).

To be clear, the JMS specification doesn't *require* the use of JNDI to look-up admin objects, but it establishes the *convention* and *expectation* that JMS providers will do so. Section 4.2 of the JMS 1.1 specification states:

> Although the interfaces for administered objects do not explicitly depend on JNDI, JMS establishes the convention that JMS clients find them by looking them up in a namespace using JNDI.

and later it says:

> It is expected that JMS providers will provide the tools an administrator needs to create and configure administered objects in a JNDI namespace. JMS
> provider implementations of administered objects should be both javax.naming.Referenceable and java.io.Serializable so that they can be stored in all JNDI naming contexts.

In my experience, JMS providers are usually eager to provide a JNDI implementation because they won't be as competitive without it since any alternative solution will not be standards compliant and will force users to implement non-portable code.

If you run into a provider that doesn't provide a JNDI implementation you could implement your own following the same pattern used by [ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.x](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/jndi/ActiveMQInitialContextFactory.java), [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jndi/ActiveMQInitialContextFactory.java), and [Qpid JMS](https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/blob/master/qpid-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/jms/jndi/JmsInitialContextFactory.java). These 3 implementations are client-side only and simply instantiate the admin objects based on the configuration provided to the `InitialContext`. Most of the code is boiler plate, and what isn't is very straight-forward.

Comment: Got it. But where does the JNDI Provider come from? Doesn't this assume that every JMS Provider library also comes with JNDI Provider in it? Is that really the case? (given that JNDI Provider is typically something embedded with the Java EE server).

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm confident that Amazon SQS doesn't provide a JNDI way of instantiating a `ConnectionFactory`. As far as I can tell it is not mandatory for a JMS Provider to use JNDI, or at least the JMS spec doesn't use the word MUST.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. There is no other option aside from JNDI to connect in a broker-agnostic way.